# Fading all images with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to fade out all my images within a table with Jquery.

The following seems not to work.Maybe a syntax error?

```
$(function() {
     $('#myTable img').each(function(index) {
        $(this).fadeOut('slow', function() {
    // Animation complete.
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe your ID is wrong : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/y9zCK/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to do this:

```
$(function() {
     $('#myTable img').fadeOut('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
       });
});
```

You don't have to use the `each` method.

And if you want to use the `each` method, do the following

```
$(function() {
     $('#myTable img').each(function(index,e) {
        $(e).fadeOut('slow', function() {
       // Animation complete.
       });
    });
});
```

The `e` will reference current image.

Comment: I need to use each cause I have to have a reference to each of the images? Thanks

Comment: Okay, I have edited my answered. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @marc This doesn't explain why his current code works. Also $(this) will refer to the image as well won't it?